# Russian train ticket for the World Cup

Tags: trains, russia, train-stations, world-cup

I'm traveling to the FIFA World Cup this summer and there was a question that came up after buying train tickets. For my USA passport I used the suffix in my name, "Jr" for Junior. But my train tickets have the correct surname and first name, but not my suffix. I didn't place one because on the online site (rzd.ru) it didn't have an option for one.

Would this be a problem or do they understand that many of the international travelers coming in for the World Cup may have non-standard names where their tickets may not exactly match their passport?

Comment: Did the ticket require you to enter your FAN ID? Then it’s the name match on the Fan ID and your passport which matters more.

Comment: Nah I purchased it from rzd.ru. it asked for last name, first name, and middle name. I left that response blank for middile name, because I don't have one. But I've been seeing people say you can put your suffix in middle name.

Comment: Years ago, up to three typos were allowed in tickets, unsure if it still holds.

Comment: @bipll Thanks for that info! I'm just used to most systems that give you a middle name option and a suffix option. Also from what I've been hearing from people is that there will be leniency to most because of the World cup.

Answer (score 3):

No, nobody will care about the suffix. Relax and enjoy your trip.

Comment: -1: while this may answer the question, some links to credible sources would be necessary.